# cant connect ec-2 with VS Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, ssh

So I have been trying to connect with the remote server using vscode but getting this error. I can connect with the remote server using powershell as administrator. I also made sure to add the correct path to my config file. I have also deleted the config and known host files before creating new connection. What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

```
[21:16:19.622] Log Level: 2
[21:16:19.626] remote-ssh@0.70.0
[21:16:19.626] win32 x64
[21:16:19.627] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+ec2-3-110-180-100.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com", attempt 1
[21:16:19.628] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[21:16:19.628] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[21:16:19.629] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[21:16:19.629] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[21:16:19.629] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\ASUS\.ssh\config
[21:16:19.629] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[21:16:19.630] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[21:16:19.630] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[21:16:19.630] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": true
[21:16:19.630] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[21:16:19.631] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[21:16:19.634] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[21:16:19.635] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[21:16:19.635] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[21:16:19.635] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[21:16:19.637] SSH Resolver called for host: ec2-3-110-180-100.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
[21:16:19.637] Setting up SSH remote "ec2-3-110-180-100.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
[21:16:19.664] Using commit id "899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3" and quality "stable" for server
[21:16:19.669] Install and start server if needed
[21:16:21.362] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[21:16:21.403] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
[21:16:21.403] > p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[21:16:21.408] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\ASUS\.ssh\config"
[21:16:21.408] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 7767 -F "C:\Users\ASUS\.ssh\config" "ec2-3-110-180-100.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com" bash
[21:16:21.412] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[21:16:21.779] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[21:16:21.779] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[21:16:21.798] > 
> [21:16:22.159] > The authenticity of host 'ec2-3-110-180-100.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.
> com (3.110.180.100)' can't be established.
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XkSx5IvSMQVKMuqzN5gAWTlM8xGAXvqQh40DubYUk
sk.
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?     
[21:16:24.233] > y
[21:16:24.427] > e
[21:16:24.813] > s
[21:16:27.069] > 
[21:16:27.090] > Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-3-110-180-100.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaw
> s.com,3.110.180.100' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
[21:16:27.422] > Load key "D:\\unive\\unive-bitnami.pem": Permission denied
[21:16:27.442] > bitnami@ec2-3-110-180-100.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission de
> nied (publickey).
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> 
[21:16:28.730] "install" terminal command done
[21:16:28.731] Install terminal quit with output: nied (publickey).
[21:16:28.732] Received install output: nied (publickey).
[21:16:28.733] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[21:16:28.735] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:430425)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:429068)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:524212)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:487216
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:490561)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:488295)
    at async c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:564197
[21:16:28.743] ------
```

Comment: Investigate `Load key "D:\\unive\\unive-bitnami.pem": Permission denied`

Comment: @jarmod I have given access rights to the administrator only removed others. When I give it only to user then even powershell doesnt connect.

Comment: Can you share your sshd config? There can be two reason for this. One, wrong permissions(depends as which user your code runs e.g admin or another user and that user has permission to read your key?). Second, bitnami user has a public key and what is the configuration for this user in sshd config file?

Comment: @Riz yes the problem was in the user. All I had to do was open the vs code in administrator mode. Thanks a lot.